# How to do searching after a particular line in Text file from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text file like below

```
Job Number - 1234  
Job Name - Vaxation  
Start Time - 29-Apr-2013 10:30   
Finish Time - 29-Mar-2013 4:00 PM  
Job Number - 2349  
Job Name - Immunity  
Start Time - 29-Apr-2013 11:30  
Finish Time - 29-Mar-2013 2:00 PM
```

The same will be repeated with different data.

I am doing the search with Job Number, if it is found then get the start time and Finish time into excel sheet.

I tried the Code below

```
Public Function ReadTxtFile()
    Dim TxtLine As String
    Dim CntRow As Integer
    Dim CntRow1 As Integer
    Dim CntRow2 As Integer

    FNum = FreeFile()

    Open TxtFile For Input As #FNum

    CntRow1 = 0

    While Not EOF(FNum)
        Line Input #FNum, TxtLine
        If InStr(1, TxtLine, "1234", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            CntRow1 = CntRow1 + 1
        Else
            CntRow2 = CntRow1 + 1
        End If
    Wend

    Call Getdat
End Function

Function Getdat()
    Seek FNum, CntRow2

    While Not EOF(FNum)
        Line Input #FNum, TxtLine

        If InStr(1, TxtLine, "StartTime", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            GLRow = ws_sh.Range("B:B").Cells.Find(Format(Now() - 1, DatFormat1), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            ws_sh.Range(Col1 & GLRow) = Format(Now() - 1, DatFormat1)
            ws_sh.Range(Col2 & GLRow) = Mid(TxtLine, 33, 5)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Are your rows/record static?  Is this a adhoc type situation, or are you creating something that will hanve many iterations?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. updated my code on above

Comment: How to do the search after the search value found (starting from that row)

Comment: Rather than parsing the file input line by line, it might be easier to import the file entirely, then process just the bits you want into a seperate file you create on the fly.  I have done similar things before and just used VBA to replicate the steps I would perform manually to get the desired results.  Filtering and copy/paste works very well this way.

Comment: its predefined template, we need to find the last row on that sheet and update the current details on it.  
Can we able to do the search after a particular line on text file ?

Comment: I agree with @AlanWaage. Read the file in the array and then loop through it. One moment. giving you an example.

Comment: So updating an pre-existing Excel file using the data from the text file.  #1 - read in file, #2 parse the needed details, #3 open Excel file, #4 loop through parsed results and for each row file the corresponding item in the excel file and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much faster method then looping though every line of the text file. You can easily convert this to a function :)

See this example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Jno As Long, JnoToCheck
    Dim strStart As String, strFinish As String

    '~~> Read the entire text file in one GO
    Open "C:\Sample.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1 '<~~ Close the text file
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    Jno = 2349

    '~~> Loop through the array
    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        '~~>. Check if it has "Job Number"
        If InStr(1, strData(i), "Job Number", vbTextCompare) Then
            '~~> Split the string to get the job no
            JnoToCheck = Val(Trim(Split(strData(i), "Job Number - ")(1)))
            '~~> Match it with the required number
            If Jno = JnoToCheck Then
                '~~> Get the relevant lines
                strStart = strData(i + 2)
                strFinish = strData(i + 3)

                Debug.Print Split(strStart, "Start Time - ")(1)
                Debug.Print Split(strFinish, "Finish Time - ")(1)                   
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]