# How can I read the rows in txt files but starting from the second row, skipping first row?

Tags: vba, excel

So this Excel Macro works great in reading multiple txt files from a specific folder and inserting all the rows in the first excel sheet. I would like to edit this code in order for the macro to skip the first row of every txt file..

Can anyone help ?

```
Sub test1()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range



    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\TXT")

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        ' Open the file
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

            ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, vbTab)

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            cl.Value = file.Name
            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Items(i)
            Next

            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop

        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close
    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you looping through every line in the text file? This will slow down your code. Read the file in one go in an array and then loop through the array. That ways you can easily skip whatever line you want. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286769/how-to-do-searching-after-a-particular-line-in-text-file-from-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 Read the first line upfront**

Before you start your Do While loop add this line:

```
If Not FileText.AtEndOfStream Then TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
```

This way you will read the first line (if any) and your Do While loop will only read the subsequent ones

**Option 2 Remove the first lines in the excel afterwards**

Another solution could be to remove the first Row in excel after your script is done importing all the files.

You might have to be specific to which columns this applies to as I am unsure if the active import is the only one (otherwise you would remove previously imported values that shouldnt have been removed at all!